# c enum with 32 bit values

Tags: c, gcc

i need some unsigned 32bit enum values for my software, therefore i implemented this (simple) enum:

```
enum{
   val1    = 0xFFFFFFFFu,
   val2    = 0xFFFFFFFEu,
   val3    = 0xFFFFFFF0
};
```

The problem: Everytime i run the compiler, Eclipse aborts compiling and marks the enum with the following error:
[image]

In my oppinion, a 32 int value should not be a problem for enums, but obviously it seems to be.
I would be grateful about some input :)

[Update 1:]  I will try to find the problem in the compiler settings, i will keep you up to date

Comment: arent't C enumerates signed values?

Comment: It's complaining because you're trying to use an unsigned literal for a signed int.

Comment: sadly, after removing the 'u' it still doesn't work (same error)

Comment: What compiler do you use ? Could you edit your code and show us a [MCVE]?

Comment: Here it compiles: http://ideone.com/Scfu6X

Comment: @MichaelWalz Ok i will look at my compiler settings, maybe i can find a solution there, thanks!

Comment: Here it compiles too (with gcc) : https://godbolt.org/g/SkHTNi. Possibly compiler flags related.

Comment: Works for me (just keep in mind that you're using negative enumerations (for all it matters)).

Comment: Since we're bragging about compilers already, clang works too.

Comment: You could just replace these with signed 32-bit values (`val1 = -1, val2 = -2, val3 = -16`)

Comment: Why would anyone brag about their compiler failing to warn for implicit conversion from large unsigned to smaller signed? That's a bad thing, not something to be proud of.

Comment: Under VS2015/2017 you can set the type with `enum XXX : DWORD` for example. Maybe it works also on gcc.

Comment: I have found numerous questions on numerous sites in the last 10 years about this exact issue without any real solution except to use static const or #define. Seems to me the C standard should be updated to allow declaration of unsigned enum { ... }; which would save a lot of headache and make this a portable mechanism without relying on compiler extensions.

Answer (score 7):

An *enumeration constant* (`val1` in your example) is required to be of type `int` by the C standard. This is a signed type and on a 32 bit system, the value `FFFFFFFF` will not fit inside it. This value will therefore get converted to a signed integer in some implementation-defined (compiler-specific) manner. If this can't be done, you'll get an implementation-defined signal.

Writing code which relies on this is bad, since it is non-portable and unpredictable. There is no compiler setting that can fix this, because this is by language design.

I believe the gcc flag `-pedantic`/`-pedantic-errors` could be removed in order to get rid of the warning, but that's a bad idea, as you will no longer follow standard C. gcc in its default, non-standard "skunk mode" `-std=gnu90` or `-std=gnu11` will compile the code, as will any `-std=cxx` without `-pedantic-errors`.

This is why enums are unsuitable for any form of bit masks or bit-wise operations.

The best solution is to get rid of the enum and use either `#define` or `const uint32_t`, whichever is most convenient for your specific scenario.

Comment: They're suitable for bitmasks that don't use the sign bit

Comment: I haven't found any compiler that complains about the OP's code event with `-pedantic-errors`. I wonder which flag we need to put in order to get a warning/error with that code.

Comment: @M.M No they really aren't, consider for example `mask << n` or  `~mask`

Comment: @MichaelWalz Then you are doing something wrong. `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors` gives `error: ISO C restricts enumerator values to range of 'int' [-Wpedantic]`

Comment: @MichaelWalz all versions of gcc I tried give the warning with `-pedantic` ... perhaps you were trying C++ compilers, or online compilers that suppress warnings

Comment: @Jabberwocky: FYI - http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0348c/Babjddhe.html
"#66: enumeration value is out of "int" range" ARM compilers will generate this warning. Also, note that C makes the behavior implementation defined. It's on Compiler's discretion to give you a warning or not. The compiler is being nice if it's generating one.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this?:

```
enum {
   val1    = (int)0xFFFFFFFFu,
   val2    = (int)0xFFFFFFFEu,
   val3    = (int)0xFFFFFFF0
};
```

Edit: I just installed gcc on cygwin and tried this out.

test-enum.c is the original version, test-enum-int.c the one with explicit casting:

```
$ cc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -c test-enum.c
test-enum.c:2:8: error: ISO C restricts enumerator values to range of 'int' [-Wpedantic]
   val1 = 0xFFFFFFFFu,
          ^
test-enum.c:3:8: error: ISO C restricts enumerator values to range of 'int' [-Wpedantic]
   val2 = 0xFFFFFFFEu,
          ^
test-enum.c:4:8: error: ISO C restricts enumerator values to range of 'int' [-Wpedantic]
   val3 = 0xFFFFFFF0u
          ^

$ cc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -c test-enum-int.c
```

(no complains)

```
$ cc --version
cc (GCC) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: This means exactly the same thing. The warning is there for a reason.

Comment: @Lundin IMHO, it is not exactly the same thing. However, I agree that forcing the C compiler this way should be done carefully and may restrict the portability.

Comment: The cast definitely changes the value. The standard only allows it to be done explicitly. Note that the conversion is implementation-defined; we're tacitly assuming two's-complement.

Answer (score 1):

ISO C before C23 restricts `enum` values to the range of `int` so to stay on the safe side you'd have to restrict yourself to a range that fits in the smallest possible `int`, which is 16 bit, giving you the range `[-32767, 32767]` of available values. `-32768` isn't possible for a 16 bit `int` on a ones' complement machine, so to be absolutely safe, stay away from that.

Since C23 you will however be able to specify the underlying type. Here's an example where the underlying type is `uint32_t`:

```c
enum : uint32_t {        // or uint_least32_t
   val1    = 0xFFFFFFFF,
   val2    = 0xFFFFFFFE,
   val3    = 0xFFFFFFF0
};
```

Or if you want to name it, the name goes before the colon:

```c
enum name : uint32_t {
   val1    = 0xFFFFFFFF,
   val2    = 0xFFFFFFFE,
   val3    = 0xFFFFFFF0
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Earlier, someone said use ideaone.com bit their code was incorrect.
you must actually USE the enum to get the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
enum{
   val1    = 0xFFFFFFFFu,
   val2    = 0xFFFFFFFEu,
   val3    = 0xFFFFFFF0
} abc ;
 
int main(void) {
 
    abc mine = val1;
    return 0;
}
```

You could restrict your enums to the signed int 0x7FFFFFFF.